# Could not extract a password protected attachment from rpmsg a file with mip sdk 1.13.161

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

We use the Inspection APIs to decrypt rpmsg files in our application. The MIP SDK v1.13.161 failed to extract the attachment from a rpmsg file which has a password protected attachment. The attachment is a password protected .docx file. The MIP SDK throws an exception, "The file has been protected using non RMS technologies...", while calling commitFuture.get() to get fileInspector for the rpmsg file. This was not an issue in version 1.8.104 that we were previously using.

Similar to v1.8, it should be possible to extract the password protected docx file from the rpmsg.

This issue can be reproduced by the mip_sdk_file_win32_1.13.161\samples\file.

1. Build samples\file.
2. Run the built file_sample with parameters: --file message_with_pw_protected_docx_attachment.rpmsg --inspect --enableMsg -u --useStreamApi

Result: The MIP SDK throws an exception, "The file has been protected using non RMS technologies..." at line "auto inspector = commitFuture.get()" in Inspect() in samples\file\main.cpp.